# Driver Logic Chain Question

Tags: scripting, node-editor, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm curious to know does there exist a topic or solution involving what I can guess as a "logic chain" (if-this-then-that) between drivers and target, to limit/control influences?

**For example of a gatekeeper:**

A. The basic use of a driver: rotation of a cube changes the value of an image's transparency (0 to 1).

B. As soon as the image's transparency value reaches to 1, a second driver is allowed to influence another node value.

C. However, keep in mind, that the second driver cannot activate until the first driver fulfill its duty.

**Limits:**

There are addons like rapidSDK and RBFDrivers, although extremely convenient for RBF purposes, don't have "logic chains," and no nodes or driver functions I can find can relate to this.

Comment: Please show your drivers in the Blender Driver editor. I find the question difficult to understand.  Perhaps others find it easy to understand.  Can you review your question to make it easier to understand?

Comment: One reason to declare variables in the Blender driver editor is so so that Blender can perform a topological sort.  Dependency Graph or DAG.  You can look up such terms if you feel the need.

Comment: The question is hard to understand for me too. Do you mean use same driver on 2 separate attribute?

Comment: I edited the question to make it a lot simpler. My apologies for the confusion. Had to think about it for a bit to make it more concise.

Comment: Hi Marquis, there is an edit history in every post. There is no need to title your post as revised or add additional text explaining an edit as it can become distracting.

Comment: Here may be a solution you want:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261174/2-way-property-link-or-a-filtered-property-display